# Unity3D Canvas scaleFactor not working correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been working on the UI of a game I am making with in this part of the UI it generates a line via script. (see below)

```
//Total Width Line
float lineTotalWidth = (gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width * Canvas.scaleFactor);

//Start Postion Line
float currentX = 0 - (transform.GetComponent<VerticalLayoutGroup>().padding.left * Canvas.scaleFactor);
float currentY = 0;
```

I calculate the line width with the with of the object * canvas.scaleFactor and this is working perfectly (see image)

[image]

But after I change the resolution the line doesn't calculate the width correctly anymore. I know this has something to do with the canvas.scaleFactor but I cant figure out what.

[image]

Does anybody know how I can make sure the line updates with the screen resolution correctly.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This documentation page may be of use: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html

Comment: I don't know what type of object your line is, but from the looks of it your code applies the scaleFactor twice. That should be the case if your line is some UI component, as this should also be auto-scaled by the canvas.

Comment: @yuri206 The line is drawn with a asset from the asset store called Vectrosity. This is a very easy way to draw UI lines but the problem is that when I change the resolution when I am playing the game the scaleFactor breaks but if I start it in a different resolution it is fine. So the problem only happens when you are playing.